# How to see tomcat log when services are running?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I'm making a web service in Java, the .war file is stored among Tomcat webapps. When it is called how could I see the output from log instructions?

```
Log.d(tag, "string");
```

Comment: Depending on how you have your logger configured, default log location for Apache Tomcat is in the logs folder.

Comment: yes, there they are. I wonder if they can be seen at runtime, not after all is done. is there a way, a configuration or a tool?

Comment: which editor are you using ? eclipse ?

Comment: I didn't think about the editor because the app is deployed in tomcat which is the execution manager

Comment: you know logcat in android studio? I was searching for something similar

Comment: I currently develop using Tomcat with IntelliJ. I configured my IntelliJ to deploy to a .war file, then use a batch file to copy the .war to the apache-tomcat-7.x.xx\webapps\ folder. From there, I just use the tomcat\bin\startup.bat, which opens the Tomcat instance in console view. I can see the log entries from there.

Answer (score 0):

See here,

suppose i have apache-tomcat which resides here,

*C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.62(For my machine).*

*First of all find you server -> logs*

see for my PC it reside here,

[image]

For eclipse IDE,

follow this path,

```
workspace directory -> .metadata -> .plugins -> org.eclipse.wst.server.core -> tmp0 -> logs -> logfilename.log
```

[image]